# copying files (cp and rsync) to external HDD causes i/o errors and loss of data on destination

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, file-copy, ntfs, external-hdd

I am trying to back up data (230 GB, 160k files), over USB3.0 to a newly bought external Seagate Expansion Portable Drive of 4 TB, formatted as NTFS. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I first tried using a simple cp command in the terminal, but after only copying a few percent, the copying started stuttering and became slow. After some time the disk became unresponsive. Remounting the disk did not work. I tried connecting the disk to another computer, and was first unable to mount it, and then after a few attempts, it would mount but read/write would be very slow.

Once the cp starts failing, I get the following errors in dmesg (all these messages are repeating multiple times but with some different numbers):

```
[67598.098118] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 19 inflight: CMD 
[67598.098122] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 1c 75 24 18 00 00 04 00 00 00
[67598.225621] usb 1-9: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[67598.378202] scsi host4: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[67598.378466] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_RESET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[67598.378468] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 1c 74 d0 18 00 00 04 00 00 00
[67598.378470] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 4772384792 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[67598.378473] buffer_io_error: 246 callbacks suppressed
[67598.378474] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 596515075, lost async page write
[67635.212662] scsi host4: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[67635.213657] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#28 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 10 inflight: CMD 
[67635.213658] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#28 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 01 1c 75 e8 18 00 00 04 00 00 00
[67635.340988] usb 1-9: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[67635.490335] scsi host4: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

I left the disk for a week, and then did a SMART scan using the Seagate Bootable Tool, which showed no issues.

Thus, I attempted copying the data again. The disk would mount properly now and I could read/write without issues, so I started an rsync command. First I did

```
rsync -avh source dest
```

It worked, albeit slowly, for about 20 % of the data, then it started stuttering so I stopped the transfer. I restarted the transfer using

```
rsync -avhW source dest --inplace
```

to try and make it faster. It ran great, much faster than the first attempt, but after a few minutes, I received errors:

```
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "..." : Input/output error (5)
rsync: write failed on "...": Input/output error (5)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(393) [receiver=3.1.2]
```

In dmesg I see the following:

```
[ 6772.890553] buffer_io_error: 1092735 callbacks suppressed
[ 6772.890556] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb2, logical block 874428, async page read
```

Once this happened, the disk became unresponsive. After a few minutes I could remount it, and checking the folder to which I was copying data it is completely empty, including the files that were properly copied during my first rsync attempt. I did not try to restore any data to see if the data was still intact, I suppose that it is only the file table that has been corrupted.

The files that were being copied at the time of failure are of type .mat.gz, on the order of 1 MB each.

As a sidenote, an old external Seagate disk recently broke when I was copying small amounts of data from it, on this computer (the infamous click of death...), which was also my first HDD ever to die.

I have no idea what to make of this, if the problem lies with how I am copying data (can copying data destroy disks?), if the problem lies with hardware (computer, HDD, USB-SATA converter, ...) or if it has to do with Ubuntu... Normally I only run Manjaro and I never experienced this kind of issues.

Comment: Have you run `fsck` or another utility to see if the HDD is actually defective? If it is, then it's not a good idea to continue to use the HDD.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of context from `dmesg`. The disk might be alright, but still it might *disappear* due to cables, USB bus, ... You should have some more messages related to the failure. `/dev/sdb2` is the external disk, right?

Comment: Can you install `smartmontools` and run a SMART check of the disk (`smartctl -a /dev/sdb`, or whatever device is appropriate). Look for messages saying "error" (of some sort) and attribute values `Raw_Read_Error_Rate`, `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`, `Power_On_Hours`, `Reported_Uncorrect`, `Reallocated_Event_Count`, `Current_Pending_Sector`, and `Offline_Uncorrectable`. Or all that table if it's easier.

Comment: What's your hardware?  Is this an add-on USB 3 adapter?  If so, try using one of the integral USB ports on your system.  Those aren't likely to be cheap junk.

Comment: The sudden slowness might be explained if it is a **shingled** drive (read eg this [article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/14539/seagate-backup-plus-portable-5tb-backup-plus-slim-2tb-review-portable-smr/3)). It does not explain io errors, which are more likely to be due to insufficient power. Use decent short usb3 cables without any intermediate unpowered hubs.

Comment: @roaima, I meant to ask if `/dev/sdb2` was *on* the external disk. Just to be sure the error from `dmesg` came from the right device.

Comment: @NasirRiley it is of NTFS file system, so fsck does not work. I could try using chkdisk from a Windows computer, but given the size of the disk that will take some time.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I provided all the messages in dmesg that I could find, which seemed relevant. I did a new (failed) attempt with CP over the night and I am updating the question with the dmesg messages.

Comment: @roaima smartmontools does not work for me with this particular external HDD. Supposedly I need to add the command -d sat,12 but it does not help. That is why I used the Seagate tool on a bootable USB stick, which reported no problems. Although I only did the SMART scan and not the in-depth scan as it would take over a day to complete.

Comment: Have you tried with other cables and ports? Also, the filesystem could be corrupt, you should try to run `ntfsfix -n` (-n will not write) to see if there are issues.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the USB3 adapter sits on the front of the chassis, so I suppose that the four USB ports are basically one hub that is connected to the motherboard through a cable. I cannot open up the PC however. I am trying one of the back ports now.

Comment: In my experience `rsync` stresses NTFS filesystem implementations horribly. I don't know why, but I've ended up installing an ext4 driver in Windows rather then using NTFS disks from Linux.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani using the back ports directly on the motherboard resulted in the same problems and dmesg error messages. I tried ntfsfix -n, but it returns: "Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing. FAILED" and ends with "unrecoverable error. Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdisk"... Maybe I should reformat the drive into ext4? The NTFS partition is from the factory.

Comment: Yes, if that's an option, do reformat it. It looks like filesystem corruption to me. (You'll lose all the information on that drive. I know you know, but just in case :) )

Comment: It looks like it's resetting the USB device?  I've had a similar experience with a USB/SATA adapter in the past.

Comment: *Maybe I should reformat the drive into ext4?*  You might want to try doing something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1024k` just to see if that works.  I'm surprised you can't read SMART data from the disk on that system - that to me is a bad sign.  Who's the system manufacturer?  And why can't you open the system up and plug the drive in directly to a SATA connector?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I will try the dd command. As for the system, it is a Dell OptiPlex 7040 (motherboard 0Y7WYT), whereas the HDD is a Seagate Expansion Portable Drive (4 TB). Trying to connect the disk internally is a good idea, but if there in fact is a problem with the disk, I would not want to void the warranty. I can read the SMART data using the official tool from Seagate, but not with smartctl ("Read device identify failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command"). I understood while troubleshooting this that it is common with USB-SATA interfaces to not be compatible with smartctl.

Comment: Check out this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541463/119298) and answer. They have a **shingled** seagate drive and are getting io errors due to enormous timeouts caused by this SMR disk architecture. They increased the timeouts and the device now works, with the usual SMR restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help.

I have now solved the issue. I reformatted the drive to ext4 and after that I used the command

```
rsync -avhW source dest --inplace --exclude=".*/"
```

where

```
-a is for archive, which preserves ownership, permissions etc.
-v is for verbose, to see what is happening
-h is for human-readable, so the transfer rate and file sizes are easier to read 
-W is for copying whole files only, without delta-xfer algorithm which should reduce CPU load
--inplace tells rsync to not create a temporary copy of the file to be transferred, which is then copied to the destination. This should speed up the process.
--exclude=".*/" is for excluding all hidden folders
```

Average data rate for 392 GB was 81.3 MB/s, which is much faster than what I achieved before reformatting the drive.

dmesg was clear of errors this time.

Note that I did not attempt to make a fresh NTFS partition on the drive to see if it was the particular NTFS paritition, from the factory, that was the problem or if it is NTFS in itself that was causing the issues. This unfortunately means that I do not have a complete answer to what the problem was. I also did not attempt to increase the timeout thresholds, but given the much faster data rate this time around, I would say that increased timeout thresholds would at best be a workaround, and not a solution.